# BlackBerry emulator Access to not allowed

Tags: cordova, blackberry

I am developing application using PhoneGap, but when I launch my application on BlackBerry emulator it keeps showing me `Access to (some link) not allowed`. 
I have tried adding to config.xml file 
`<access origin="*"/>`
 `<access origin="https://somedomain.com" subdomains="true" />`

 But the message still keeps showing. The application works on Android.
Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it myself just had to add `<preference name="websecurity" value="disable" />`